# Why doesn't Vue show up?

Tags: django, vue.js

I just started to learn using Vue. I wrote really simple code like the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <div id="app">
            <h2>{{number}}</h2>
            <h2>Here it is!</h2>
        </div>
    </body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                number:0
            }
        })

</script>
</html>
```

However, there is no `number` value.

[image]

But, when I open that code just by `Ctrl+O` on chrome, it shows succefully!

[image]

I definitely checked `network` by chrome dev tool and I got successfully `vue.js` from `https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.22/dist/vue.js` What's wrong with it?

Comment: try to load script in head tag <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

Comment: @ShafikurRahman Thanks for your advice.. but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Loading the framework in the head is a good way to start.
See the example below, it works fine in here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h2>{{number}}</h2>
            <h2>Here it is!</h2>
            <button @click="clk">click</button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
              number: 0
          },
          methods: {
            clk(){
              this.number++;
            }
          }
        })

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I open that code by just 'ctrl+O' on chrome like `file:///C:/Users/1Sun/front/templates/test.html`, it shows successfully, but it doesn't work in local server like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cebula/test`

Comment: running a local serving should work as well. Make sure you start a new html file with the example code above.

Comment: I already did it but not succeeded.. i'm using DRF in backend, Can this happen to be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 0):

I thought you should return an object from a function for data.

data : function() {
 return {
    number : 0
 };
}

Comment: Really thanks for your answer.. but It cannot show :(